# flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.0 and bookingapp depends on intl ^0.17.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is forbidden

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-localizations

Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.0 and bookingapp depends on intl ^0.17.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is forbidden.
So, because bookingapp depends on flutter_localizations from sdk, version solving failed.

Process finished with exit code 1

Please help me to solve this issue, I tried to import old project in android studio.

environment:
sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

Flutter v-  3.10.2

Android Studio (version 2022.2)

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency override to the pubspec.yml

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: any
```

Comment: This works during debug. but when building an android bundle or apk, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

`Flutter Localization` has been update to depend on `intl` 0.18. See latest comment here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117163

You just edit your `pubspec.yaml` like this

```
 flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0  # Change from 0.17 -> 0.18
```

And run `flutter pub get`, it will error free

Answer (score 0):

Update intl version to:

```
dependencies:
  intl: any
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works during debug. but when building an android bundle or apk, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved by:

- upgrading the **latest Flutter SDK**
- ensuring I was using all of the latest versions within pubspec for both **dependencies** and **dev_dependencies**.

After making sure I was using the latest versions (as of July 6th 2023) version solving resolved OK.

**Pubspec.yaml:**

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
  ...
```

**Flutter version:**

```
Flutter 3.10.5 • channel stable 
Tools • Dart 3.0.5 • DevTools 2.23.1
```